# [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1531N

Tags: python, db2

I am a beginner at Data Science, taking up IBM Certification.

I need to complete this [lab](https://notebooks.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?color_mode=auto&commit=240c88451bc8d648e6fadb37bfbecb68db3403ac&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f676973742f6368737265656b61722f38386631383466616264396363616265623730646563353736353734666464362f7261772f323430633838343531626338643634386536666164623337626662656362363864623334303361632f444230323031454e2d5765656b332d312d312d436f6e6e656374696e672d76342d70792e6970796e62&logged_in=false&nwo=chsreekar%2F88f184fabd9ccabeb70dec576574fdd6&path=DB0201EN-Week3-1-1-Connecting-v4-py.ipynb&repository_id=98451767&repository_type=Gist) as my course content. However, I am getting the captioned error when I try to **"Create the DB2 database connection"** on Anaconda Jupyter Notebook.

**My code is:**

conn = ibm_db.connect("BLUDB", "scm36847", "XXX")

**My ERROR Message says:**

Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1531N  The connection failed because the name specified with the DSN connection string keyword could not be found in either the db2dsdriver.cfg configuration file or the db2cli.ini configuration file.  Data source name specified in the connection string: "BLUDB". SQLCODE=-1531

**UPDATE: **

If you are talking about the following, I have done this:

conn = ibm_db.connect("BLUDB", "scm36847", "XXX")
print ("Connected to BLUDB: ", BLUDB, "as 9938aec0-8105-433e-8bf9-0fbb7e483086.c1ogj3sd0tgtu0lqde00.databases.appdomain.cloud: ", dsn_uid, "scm36847: ", dsn_hostname)

but then I get the error.

Comment: You do not appear to be following instructions that are in your lab notebook, in particular the cell number two, that begins "#Replace the placeholder values with your actual Db2 hostname, username, and password:"  Instead your question shows you are only passing a database-name (and uid/password), but you omitted the driver, port, protocol and hostname. So the clidriver does not know how to find "bludb" and tell you this.

Comment: Please check the update in my original query

Comment: So, did you edit either `db2dsdriver.cfg` or  `db2cli.ini` to define the DSN BLUDB?

Comment: I didnt edit any od them and I don't even know how to do that, if needed! Thats y I am having error, I suppose

Comment: It is not necessary to edit either of those files to get a connection. (You can if you want to, but it is not essential, and if it was necessary then the notebook would explain that). The cells in the notebook explain what you must do, but it appears that you are not following those instructions correctly, if code shown in your question really is what you are doing.

Comment: Well, Can v talk on Zoom?